# How to remove area-require attribute in rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, simple-form, simple-form-for

This is a checkbox  which has required attribute `true`

This form belongs to form component made using simple form

```
= form.input :terms, label: "hello", as: :boolean, required: true
```

But when this is converted into HTML (rendered by RAILS), we get this result

```
<input class="boolean required" required="required" aria-required="true" type="checkbox" value="1" name="sample_name" id="sample_id">
```

The above code contains an extra attribute called `aria-required` which comes with `require` attribute from HAML file.

It is said that simple form automatically adds the this `aria-required` attribute.

How to remove the `aria-required` attribute from the form without removing `required` attribute?

Comment: Where does `form.input` come from?

Comment: It's  simple form gem